# jquery validate input array and passing dynamic values

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I'm trying to validate a group of input arrays using jquery validator plugin. I'm having problems understanding how to pass another element into the validation.

My code so far:

```
$('#edit-fixtures').validate({
            rules: {
                "player_a[]": {
                    required: true,
                    uniqueMatch: function () {
                        return $(this).next('.player').val();
                    },
                },
                "player_b[]": {
                    required: true,
                    uniqueMatch: function () {
                        $(this).closest('.player').val();
                    },
                },
            }
        });
```

My input elements are a series of paired select boxes named `player_a[]` `player_b[]` There are about 40 pairs. Each pair should be unique and that's what i'll be validating.

I'm trying to pass the value of the nearest player_b to the changed player_a and vice versa.

I have a change method to validate on each change:

```
$(".player").change(function () {

            var check = $(this).valid();

            console.log("validation:", check);

        });
```

I'm still working on the validation method but cant seem to get the parameters to the method correctly.

Is there a way of doing this?

Comment: Hi- yes it is, i;ve tried different approaches - neither mehtod really works - have changed the post to avoid confusion - thanks for pointing out.

Answer (score 0):

```
uniqueMatch: [$item1, $item2, ....]

$.validator.addMethod('uniqueMatch', function(value, element, parameterValue) {
    var item1Value = $(parameterValue[0]).val();
    //and so on...
    //Based on values, you return true or false;
    //Voila!
}
```